# How to make a subview automatically resize with its superview?

Tags: iphone

I have a view which contains one sub-view; this sub-view itself contains another sub-view, which is meant to be slightly smaller than its superview.

I am creating the first subview full-screen size then shrinking it to a very small size on the screen.  When the subview is tapped, I animate it from its small size to full-screen.

The problem is that my second subview never resizes itself during this animation - it is always rendered full-size and overflows the bounds of its superview.

Is there a simple way to get a subview to keep itself sized proportionally as its superview changes size?

Answer (score 32):

you could add the autoresizing-behavior programmatically

**Objective-C**

```
subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
subview.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

In Interface-Builder navigate to tab 3 and click on the arrows in the middle ;D

Another workaround could be to implement the setFrame-method and always adapt it to the size of the superview (not the given frame.size). Don't forget to set up the origin as you need it.

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGRect rect = self.superview.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    [super setFrame:rect];
}
```

Comment: Well, since this is part of the UIView, try UIKit `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: Well, that works, but it doesn't seem to be resizing the subview proportionally. If I increase the width of the superview by a factor of 2, the width of the subview increases by a factor of 4. Is there any way to get the subview to maintain its proportional size relative to the superview?

Comment: you added an extra "Mask" to those constants.

Comment: The autoresizing is used to resize proportionally exactly to the size of the superview. And this is were the problem lies. If you set up the frame of the view (not superview) programmatically, it will change the whole appearance of the view. Did you leave your code-snippets where you changed the frame of the subview?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The only time I programmatically set the frame of the subview is in the superview's `initWithFrame` method (in which I create the subview with alloc/initWithFrame and set its autoresizing mask). Thereafter, when I change the size of the superview programmatically, my expectation is that the subview will maintain its size proportionally to the superview, but this isn't happening.

Comment: In swift 2.x the syntax is now: `subview.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]`

Comment: What if reverse , Increase Height or width of Superview according to change height and width of subview ? is it possible

Comment: @MikeAlter Please create a new question for this, as this is also related to whether you implement NSLayoutConstraints or not and might be more complex to discuss it in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

this does the trick for me

```
subview.frame = subview.superview.bounds;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using only [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] for your autoresizing mask, your subview will not get resized proportionally. The right answer is:

```
autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
```